# Correct way to import custom handlebar helpers to assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

Have the following assemble file, and everything is loading as expected. The file compiles if I use the handlebars-helpers, but its missing the helpers I need. So I had to use a custom helper file/module

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var assemble = require('assemble');
//var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers');
var app = assemble();
var prettify = require('gulp-prettify');
var config = require('../config');

gulp.task('init', function(cb) {
  app.helpers(config.paths.path_src + 'partials/_helpers/is-helper.js');
  //app.helper('compare', helpers.comparison());
  app.partials(config.paths.path_src + 'templates/includes/**/*.hbs');
  app.layouts(config.paths.path_src + 'templates/layouts/**/*.hbs');
  app.pages(config.paths.path_src + 'templates/content/**/*.hbs');
  cb();
});

gulp.task('assemble', ['init'], function() {
  return app.toStream('pages')
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(prettify({
        indent_inner_html: false,
        preserve_newlines: true,
        end_with_newline: true,
        extra_liners: ['head', 'body']
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: '.html'
    }))
    .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
    .pipe(app.dest('site'));
});

gulp.task('test', ['assemble']);
```

Now I already tried handlebars-helper but it does not have the helper file I am after so I had to use the one below:

```
/*
    Custom handlebars helpers which allows to make

    {{#is a '===' b}}}

    {{/is}}
*/

module.exports.register = function (handlebars) {

    var isArray = function(value) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
    }

    var ExpressionRegistry = function() {
        this.expressions = [];
    };

    ExpressionRegistry.prototype.add = function (operator, method) {
        this.expressions[operator] = method;
    };

    ExpressionRegistry.prototype.call = function (operator, left, right) {
        if ( ! this.expressions.hasOwnProperty(operator)) {
            throw new Error('Unknown operator "'+operator+'"');
        }

        return this.expressions[operator](left, right);
    };

    var eR = new ExpressionRegistry;
    eR.add('not', function(left, right) {
        return left != right;
    });
    eR.add('>', function(left, right) {
        return left > right;
    });
    eR.add('<', function(left, right) {
        return left < right;
    });
    eR.add('>=', function(left, right) {
        return left >= right;
    });
    eR.add('<=', function(left, right) {
        return left <= right;
    });

    eR.add('==', function(left, right) {
        return left == right;
    });

    eR.add('===', function(left, right) {
        return left === right;
    });
    eR.add('!==', function(left, right) {
        return left !== right;
    });
    eR.add('in', function(left, right) {
        if ( ! isArray(right)) {
            right = right.split(',');
        }
        return right.indexOf(left) !== -1;
    });

    var isHelper = function() {
        var args = arguments
        ,   left = args[0]
        ,   operator = args[1]
        ,   right = args[2]
        ,   options = args[3]
        ;


        // console.log(args);

        if (args.length == 2) {
            options = args[1];
            if (left) return options.fn(this);
            return options.inverse(this);
        }

        if (args.length == 3) {
            right = args[1];
            options = args[2];
            if (left == right) return options.fn(this);
            return options.inverse(this);
        }

        if (eR.call(operator, left, right)) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
        return options.inverse(this);
    };

    handlebars.registerHelper('is', isHelper);

    return eR;
};
```

I keep getting the following error missing helper "is". Looks like its not registering! **Please help!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to [this github issue](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/822#issuecomment-325755794):

The `is` helper documentation is [here](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#is).

> Also is there a way to import custom helpers?

This is described [here](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/templates#helper).
Instead of using a path, you use `require`:

```
// single helper (required module returns the helper function)
app.helper('is', require('./helpers/is'));

// multiple helpers (required module returns an object of helper functions... e.g. key/value pairs)
app.helpers(require('./helpers'));
```

The above custom helper code is using the `grunt-assemble` syntax for registering helpers. In this case, I would change your helper to look like this:

```
/*
    Custom handlebars helpers which allows to make

    {{#is a '===' b}}}

    {{/is}}
*/

module.exports = function () {

    var isArray = function(value) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
    }

    var ExpressionRegistry = function() {
        this.expressions = [];
    };

    ExpressionRegistry.prototype.add = function (operator, method) {
        this.expressions[operator] = method;
    };

    ExpressionRegistry.prototype.call = function (operator, left, right) {
        if ( ! this.expressions.hasOwnProperty(operator)) {
            throw new Error('Unknown operator "'+operator+'"');
        }

        return this.expressions[operator](left, right);
    };

    var eR = new ExpressionRegistry;
    eR.add('not', function(left, right) {
        return left != right;
    });
    eR.add('>', function(left, right) {
        return left > right;
    });
    eR.add('<', function(left, right) {
        return left < right;
    });
    eR.add('>=', function(left, right) {
        return left >= right;
    });
    eR.add('<=', function(left, right) {
        return left <= right;
    });

    eR.add('==', function(left, right) {
        return left == right;
    });

    eR.add('===', function(left, right) {
        return left === right;
    });
    eR.add('!==', function(left, right) {
        return left !== right;
    });
    eR.add('in', function(left, right) {
        if ( ! isArray(right)) {
            right = right.split(',');
        }
        return right.indexOf(left) !== -1;
    });

    var isHelper = function() {
        var args = arguments
        ,   left = args[0]
        ,   operator = args[1]
        ,   right = args[2]
        ,   options = args[3]
        ;


        // console.log(args);

        if (args.length == 2) {
            options = args[1];
            if (left) return options.fn(this);
            return options.inverse(this);
        }

        if (args.length == 3) {
            right = args[1];
            options = args[2];
            if (left == right) return options.fn(this);
            return options.inverse(this);
        }

        if (eR.call(operator, left, right)) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
        return options.inverse(this);
    };

    return isHelper;
};
```

The in assemble you can load the helper by doing:

```
var isHelper = require(config.paths.path_src + 'partials/_helpers/is-helper'));
app.helper('is', isHelper());
```

Notice that the returned function from the `is-helper` is called before passing it to `app.helper`. This allows you to pass custom options to your helper (e.g. custom expressions that you're using in your helper), but that's up to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to import the new format you gave me, its showing the following error 

Cannot find module '.src/partials/_helpers/is-helper'

I am 100% sure the module is there, but it looks like its not registering. Its very odd..

Comment: That's a node `require` error. The path is probably incorrect in relation to the app... also if the path is actually `.src/partials/_helpers/is-helper` then you'll need to add a `./` before it so node knows it's relative and not from `node_modules`: `./.src/partials/_helpers/is-helper`

Comment: That did it! I had to add ../